# schedule appointment logic: Python code with selenium

Tags: python

[Select a Data and Time Need Python and selenium logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcW5m.png)

Good Evening!
I have attached one picture what I require from all of you is need logic for the added picture. I am learning python(pycharam) with selenium automation. I have come cross one scenario where in I have to schedule an appointment by selecting the 'month' and date as '16' and time as '1:30pm'

If I get the logic for month, I will try for weekly.

I would appreciate it, if someone answering if they can share step by steps what needs to be done. I would appreciate it.

Regards,
Shiva

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('url')

elem = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('id_of_the_drop_down_list'))

# select by visible text
elem.select_by_visible_text('text_that_you_want_to_choose')
/
# select by index
elem_select_by_index(0)
/
# select by value
elem.select_by_value('1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elem = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('tt_form_ChoiceSelect_0'))
elem.select_by_visible_text('15 Available') 
elem.select_by_value('2021-02-16T19:30:00.000Z').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='nextBtn']").click()
```

Worked above logic. Its working .Thanks